# Drawing dynamical trajectories diagram in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix, dynamic

I've a Boolean gene regulation system composed of vectors(corresponding to cellular phenotypes). Their components are binary numbers such as $\{1,0,0,1\}$. A vector can change its statement in timesteps. For example $\{1,0,0,1\} \longrightarrow \{1,1,0,0\} \longrightarrow \{0,0,1,0\}$, etc.

I know there are several programs doing that but can I draw a vector flow diagram in *Mathematica*? I mean every vector will correspond to a node(or point) and go to one another.
If

$\{1,0,0,1\} = a, \{1,1,0,0\} = b, \{0,0,1,0\} = c$, where $a,b,c$ are constants,

then we have $a \longrightarrow b \longrightarrow c$.

The way above is just what i thought. Maybe there are more efficient ones.

Here is a link of the article containing what I exactly want [Figure 2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2200#)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this code answers the question:

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {120, 4}];

edges = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1];

Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

### Continuation...

Because of a question in a comment here is some code that shows the derivation of graphs, spanning trees of those graphs, their disjoint union, and a highlighted connecting path between them. I used disjoint union for clarity (with those random data graphs) -- regular graph union is probably desired with the actual data.

```
{data1, data2, data3} = 
  Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, 4}], {n, {120, 80, 70}}];
{gr1, gr2, gr3} = 
 Map[Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]] &, {data1, data2, 
   data3}]
```

[image]

```
{tr1, tr2, tr3} = Map[FindSpanningTree[#] &, {gr1, gr2, gr3}]
```

[image]

```
gr = GraphDisjointUnion[tr1, tr2, tr3, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
connectingEdges = 
  DirectedEdge @@@ 
   Partition[
    Most[Accumulate[
      Prepend[Length[VertexList[#]] & /@ {gr1, gr2, gr3}, 1]]], 2, 
    1];
HighlightGraph[EdgeAdd[gr, connectingEdges], connectingEdges]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. One more thing, if I have 3 datasets like data1, data2, data3 can I make a tree plot both contain the three data flow(flow scheme)? It will have intersections(overlaps) between datasets. Please have a look at the figure 2 in the article I mentioned.

Comment: @Haliki I looked into Figure 2 of the linked article. I don't have time to read the article in order to understand how that figure is derived. Please see my question update.

Comment: I think `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` should select the proper root vertex for a directed tree.  If not, it has ` "RootVertex"` suboption.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention. That worked for me. Best regards.

Comment: @Haliki Great! I am glad it is working out.

Comment: Tree graph structure for each data and avoiding self-loops are amazing. Lastly I want to show you something in the link below. If it is possible, I wonder that all the data1, data2 and data3 are combined in the same graph. That means no repetitive nodes in different trees. There will be one intersecting tree of all 3 trees. Everything is detailed on the picture in the link. Black arrows shows each data and nodes. And red arrows show the same nodes in different data. Finally the "flow diagram" (right side of the page) is exactly what I want. http://pdfsr.com/pdf/flow-1

Comment: gr = GraphUnion[tr1, tr2, tr3, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
DirectedEdge @@@ 
  Partition[
   Most[Accumulate[
     Prepend[Length[VertexList[#]] & /@ {gr1, gr2, gr3}, 1]]], 2, 1]; Finally it's done. Thank you again. I m fairly new to Mathematica world.

Comment: @Haliki Good. If you think it is a good idea, consider updating my answer with your code.